# OpenGL - Z- Buffer translucency

Tags: opengl, 2d, transparency

So lately I wanted to use the Z buffer in opengl to order my 2D sprites in my program. Now I didn;t relaize that if you use the Z buffer then you cant blend these sprites. And some of these sprites are translucent.

My question is what can I do to fix this, by still using the handly Z buffer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't, at least not for writes.  Z-buffer writing/ordering and transparency is not really something you can do easily.  Most techniques require significantly more work than you're likely prepared for, like using [depth peeling](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10/opengl/src/dual_depth_peeling/doc/DualDepthPeeling.pdf).

Sort your objects.  Typically you would sort opaque (or alpha cutout) objects front-to-back with Z-buffering enabled, then do a second pass of any translucent objects sorted back-to-front with Z-buffer writes disabled (but Z-testing still enabled!).  Doing the opaque front-to-back typically helps performance when you have a lot of overdraw (overlapping objects/sprites) by avoiding drawing the same pixel fragment more than once.

The problem with Z-buffering is that there is no way for the Z-buffer to both know what the closest opaque (occluding) pixel is (in a hardware-friendly way, at least), and even if it could, *transparency order matters* for some blending modes.  If you blend A onto B you will get a different color than if you blend B onto A in many common blending modes.  You *must* sort the objects to get the correct output, with or without Z-buffering issues.  You also need to draw the opaque objects first to blend over them.

Larger 3D engines typically handle this by having multiple *render queues* that sort and batch objects separately.  Opaque objects can end up in one queue with Z-buffering on, and maybe with front-to-back sorting on.  Translucent order-dependent objects end up in a different queue with Z writes off but reads on (you don't want to blend in translucent objects that are behind the opaque scenery!).  Translucent order-independent objects (additive-blending particles most often) can be put in yet another queue with no sorting at all, Z-writes off (Z-reads still on).  You can also have multiple render queues for things like UI overlays and such.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this now, but how do you decide that which texture is opaque and which is transparent? I mean do we have to mark them? If yes, I haven't seen any of the game engines to ask you to do this. Does this mean they recognize this themselves?

Comment: @MahanGM: Most engines determine this by the material (specifically, whether the alpha-blending render state is enabled for the material) rather than from the image itself.

Comment: One more question, would this sorting turn into an overhead over time? I mean in case of an engine with orthographical camera when you bring more objects to draw and they're constantly changing their z axis to make depth, you need to reorder your opaque and transparent objects every frame. Will this turn into an overhead?

Comment: @MahanGM: obviously it's an overhead. Will it be problematic? Depends on your game. You don't have a ton of choice: either you sort, you implement some kind of order-independent transparency (which have many limitations or their own massive perf problems), or you avoid the kinds of translucency that need sorting. A high-quality sort of render queue items can be extremely efficient and naive implementations (even just `std::sort`) will be quite good enough for most non-AAA games.

Comment: I hope that's good enough for my application because that's what I'm doing now. Thank you for sharing your information, really helpful.

Comment: I was able to implement sprite priorities by `discard`-ing fragments if their alpha was zero in the fragment shader, but there was still some sort of "halo" around the sprites. I wonder if this could be eliminated. Also not keen on discarding fragments as the fragment shader is relatively expensive, but tbh it did not visually effect performance.